# windows 10 settings window wont scroll, but other windows work fine

Tags: windows, windows-10, scrolling

I have just ungraded to windows 10,

but the settings window, and the start paneled window wont scroll when i scroll the mouse.

other apps like chrome, excel even explorer work fine.

what do i need to do to get the settings to work, or is this a microsoft fix needed?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/948603/windows-10-scroll-wheel-not-working-in-all-windows?rq=1 See if any of the various answers here apply.

Comment: No none of them work for me.
the mouse scroll works fine in chrome for example, but not in the windows windows, like settings?

Comment: I was having this issue today. I set my display to go tall instead of wide so I could see everything, and it turns out the window was trying to load content below what I could see before. It was locking up the entire window, making scrolling impossible. Actually, clicking buttons was impossible too. Still not sure how to fix it, though. :P

Answer (score 1):

Do you have, perhaps, Wizmouse installed on your machine? If you do then you probably know this but this software enables scrolling of inactive windows.

Worked great back when I had Windows 7 installed. Come Windows 10 and I'm able to scroll to any window except the Start menu and other native apps and settings. Thanks to this [answer](https://superuser.com/questions/948603/windows-10-scroll-wheel-not-working-in-all-windows/954883#954883), I resolved the issue by uninstalling Wizmouse. Windows 10 has native inactive window scrolling feature, anyway.

Comment: No.
the mouse scroll works fine in chrome for example, but not in the windows windows, like settings?

Answer (score 0):

The software DesktopOK also has a 'scroll inactive windows' feature which apparently collides with Windows 10's own function.

I had that still enable from before the Upgrade to Win10 and disabling it resolved the problem.